# Safari not accepting website certificate

Tags: safari, keychain, certificate

I've been using an internal website at work without any issues until today when I received the error message:

> "Safari can't open the page "https://...". The error is: "The server "..." did not accept the certificate." (NSURLErrorDomain:-1205)

I've looked in my Keychain to see if there was a certificate that I could delete and re-add, but nothing shows up there matching the URL of the website. I've fixed this problem once in the past (accidentally) by deleting my entire keychain and starting over but I didn't mean to do it the first time and I'd rather not do it again.

The website does load without an issue in other browsers without any errors/warnings. It's just Safari that's barfing.

Has anyone else seen this? Know how to fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've since solved the problem, though I'm not sure if this is the right answer for everyone.

The problem seemed to come from the certificate automatically generated from apple (com.apple.idms.appleid.prd.[large character string]). A quick Google search didn't tell me what this certificate was for, but I'm sure that deleting it was probably not the best solution. Ignoring that thought, I deleted it anyway and now I can log in without a problem. I'm sure that something bad will happen with other things on my computer (private key, other certificates, something), but it hasn't happened yet so I'm calling it a win.

UPDATE:

A couple of months on, I still haven't had anything bad happen so I guess this solution didn't break anything else.

UPDATE 2:

About a year on, this problem still comes up from time to time (even with 10.10). I keep deleting the certificate in the keychain and it keeps working for a while.

Comment: I must say, I've had this same issue after the migration to Mavericks, and deleting the `com.apple.idms.appleid.prd.*` certificate did solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

Have a look in

> /etc/certificates

for certificates that begin with your certificate name.

Check for any duplicates of the name with different GUID values.  If this is the case you will find that the certificate has either been updated or replaced at some point and is still registered to an application.

Check ***.plist** files for the particular certificate name to find where it is being used.  Then you can determine how to fix that particular case.

Answer (score 0):

Open Keychain Access to examine your Certificates. Sometimes I trash expired ones .. but instead of deleting a Certificate, you can tell the system to trust it. That's the place to do so.

Comment: That wont work for this case as safari is sending a CLIENT certificate to the server and the server is rejecting it.