# I have several hundred expired certificates starting with com.apple.idms.appleid.prd. What are they and are they safe to delete?

Tags: macos, keychain, certificate

I recently looked at Keychain Access and found that I have 394 certificates prefixed with `com.apple.idms.appleid.prd`, all of which are expired.

[image]

When I get more info on one of them, I see that it is from the Apple Certification Authority.

[image]

What are these certificates? Why do I have so many of them?

I tried to delete them and got this scary warning:

[image]

Unfortunately, I am not certain that I no longer need the selected key. So I'd like to ask: will I be needing the hundreds of expired keys, and is it safe to delete them?

Comment: Something interesting, I looked at the advanced options of my account (System Preferences > Users & Groups > right-click on account) and one of my user aliases is com.apple.idms.appleid.prd.<similar GUID>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expired certificates can be safely deleted.

They were likely generated as a result of a problem authenticating with iCloud.

Comment: Do you have any sources or anything to back this up? While I'm inclined to trust you that they can be deleted, that seems to go against what the dialog box is telling me where it asks me if I still need it.

Comment: The dialog box is telling you that _if_ you still need it, deleting it would be bad. _Expired_ certificates are not used by any reputable software to authenticate anything, certainly not for Apple software. If you [search Google for idms.appleid.prd](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=idms.appleid.prd) others have had this same issue. If the certificates were still valid, it might be different, but expired certificates are useless.

Comment: Also see http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/94379/safari-not-accepting-website-certificate, particularly the accepted answer where the user reports no ill effects from deleting this particular kind of certificate.

Comment: It seems strange that if expired certificates are not used by anyone that Keychain Access would be warning about this. I had seen some search results, but either they talked about obsolete solutions (e.g. running Keychain First Aid, which doesn't exist in recent versions of OS X), or were of questionable authority.

Comment: This is related and features an interesting answer: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5201497